# How implementation margin-bottom for position: absolute element

Tags: html, css

I don't know how in this case implementation `margin-bottom` for `position: absolute` element.
This is css of my element:

```
font-family: FuturaRoundBold;
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 15%;
top: -5%;
color: #000;
width: 75%;
padding: 1%;
background-color: rgba(233, 233, 233, 1);
border-radius: 30px;
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
-khtml-border-radius: 30px;
z-index: 2;
```

Thanks for any ideas!

[image]

Comment: I'm sure theres a question here somewhere...

Comment: You could add another transparent element under this window.

Comment: There are probably alot of elements in that page, which are you talking about?

Comment: @Sam, you are could look to bottom of the attach screenshot.

Comment: @Arthur, do you want the white element on the screen to have a bottom margin?

Comment: @Sam, yes. Good propose solution is add spacer. Look to bottom answer and upper comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin-bottom` will only do anything to an `absolute`ly-positioned element if the element has no top property.

Remove the `top: -5%` and then your `margin-bottom` will work.

Or as mentioned in the comments you can also add a transparent div like this

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

inside your outside div

```
.spacer {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 -50px 0;
    /* margin: 20px 0 -50px 0; use this if you want #container to have a 'bottom padding', in this case of 20px */
    background: transparent; /* you'll need this if #container's parent element has a different background from #container itself */
}
```

courtesy : Joey

Comment: Remove the top: -5% and then your margin-bottom will work. Top -5% - it is not being. But add spacer - good idea. Strange why just do not understand. Thanks for answer.